# What decimal precision should be given for the diagonal so that length can be calculated properly for a rectangle

Tags: math, decimal, rounding

> The diagonal of a rectangle is 15.62 inches and the width is 10 inches. What is the length? **_** inches

The answer is length = 12 inches.

If you have a precision of 2 decimal places in the diagonal, it doesn't result in an exact value for the length.

Is this question appropriate for school children or should I give a precision of 3 decimal places so that length can be calculated properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One issue is that 15.62 isn't the exact diagonal for sides of 10 and 12.  It's `15.620499351813308` or so.

Comment: so should I mention the above number as it is without rounding? Would like to know how to frame the question, so that this isn't an issue

Comment: If the point is the equation itself, why not choose a Pythagorean triple like, `5^2 + 12^2 = 13^2`? If the point is to do arithmetic with decimal places, then you can choose a Pythagorean triple divided by a certain number (like 10). That is 0.5 and 1.2 produce a hypotenuse length of 1.3.

Comment: Unless you choose the numbers carefully (such as by using a Pythagorean triple), at least one of the square roots won't be a rational number, so no finite decimal representation will be exact.